# How to force CmsSigner to use RSASSA-PSS (RsaPss) when signing with an X509Certificate with RSA assymetric parameters

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, rsa, pkcs#7

I am creating signed & encrypted pkcs 7 data.
The certificates that I use to generate signatures are issued by an external party (goverment agency).

The 'other-side' only supports signatures based on a SHA256 digest, computed using RSASSA-PSS, but CmsSigner (internally used by SignedCms) automatically chooses 'plain RSA'.

Creating an RSASSA-PSS (or RsaPss) signature would not be problem. The issue at hand is that CmsSigner seems to choose the signature algorithm, based on the certificate's key pair algorithm.

Code snippet:

```
public static byte[] EncryptDotNet(P12Keystore p12KeyStore, byte[] secret, params Etk[] etks)
    {
        if (etks == null || etks?.Any() == false)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(etks));
        }

        var authenticationCertificate = p12KeyStore.AuthenticationCert;

        var cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, authenticationCertificate)
        {
            IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly,
            DigestAlgorithm = new Oid(oidDigestAlgoSHA256)
        };

        var content = new ContentInfo(secret);
        var innerSignedCms = new SignedCms(content);
        innerSignedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner, true);

        if (innerSignedCms.SignerInfos[0].SignatureAlgorithm.Value != signatureAlgorithmRSASSAPSS)
        {
            //---> does not comply with expectation.
        }
```

I have tried using reflection to setting the the algorithm oid for RSASSA-PSS to the public/private key of the certificate, didn't seem to have an impact.
Now I am wondering if I can take the RSA output and do the PSS padding myself?
Anyhow, I am open to all suggestions...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RSASSA-PSS in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263388/rsassa-pss-in-c-sharp)

Comment: .NET Framework, .NET Core, or both?

Comment: Doing this in .NET 4.7.2.   Not a duplicate of other RSASS-PSS questions, since it is more a question of how to influence the CmsSigner to use RSASSA-PSS instead of plain RSA.

Comment: @bartonjs Your comment *".NET Framework, .NET Core, or both?"* here seems to indicate you might indeed have an idea how to make `CmsSigner` create RSASSA-PSS signatures in .NET Framework and/or .NET Core. Do you? Would you explain?

Comment: @bartonjs my question stems from use of .NET Framework and is still very relevant to me

Comment: Sorry, I keep getting distracted when trying to prove to myself I’ve remembered right. IIRC: In .NET Framework you can get RSA-PSS if the certificate uses the RSA-PSS OID for the public key, but can’t force it with the .NET API otherwise. For .NET5/Core on Linux it’s not possible at all, and I don’t remember if .NET5 on Windows is like Framework or Linux in this respect. Please open an issue saying you’d like to do this at https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues. (Answer in comment because it’s unverified recollection)