Document signing problem with Bouncy Castle based on RSA-PSS with a salt of 32 bytes in C#
I'm trying to sign a document for beA with Bouncy Castle based on RSA-PSS with a salt of 32 bytes but I get an error from the server.
This is the error I get back "400 Bad Request: error: soap:Server 0950 - CRAM authentication failed".
I have no experience with document signing and cryptography and I guess that's why I'm wrong.
I've read and searched, but this is as far as my knowledge goes, which isn't great anyway.
This is the method I use.
I get the private key as an XML and the signing document as a string. The result is base64.
public void SignData(string PrivateKeyXml, string DataToSign, out string SignedData)
{
    
    byte[] dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DataToSign);

    AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey = ImportPrivateKeyFromXml(PrivateKeyXml);

    ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256withRSAandMGF1");

    signer.Init(true, privateKey);

    signer.BlockUpdate(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
    byte[] signature = signer.GenerateSignature();

    SignedData = Convert.ToBase64String(signature);

}

private static AsymmetricKeyParameter ImportPrivateKeyFromXml(string xml)
{
    var rsa = RSA.Create();
    rsa.FromXmlString(xml);
    var parameters = rsa.ExportParameters(true);

    RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters privateKey = new RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters(
        new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(1, parameters.Modulus),
        new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(1, parameters.Exponent),
        new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(1, parameters.D),
        new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(1, parameters.P),
        new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(1, parameters.Q),
        new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(1, parameters.DP),
        new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(1, parameters.DQ),
        new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(1, parameters.InverseQ));

    return privateKey; 
}



Is there any reason you are using BouncyCastle in the first place, rather than builtin libraries https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944523/14868997
